# Disabling & Enabling is not launching the finder sync extension

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, macos-sierra, findersync

[image]

Finder Sync Extensions can be enabled or disabled from the extension's settings in System Preferences.

My Extension isn't launching with the application, even when the check mark for the extension is enabled.

So to launch the extension, i disable my extension and enable it again. This isn't launching the extension app?

Is thus wanted to know if i am missing any aspect here.

Note: If the app is running, and i disable the extension, it quits the extension app (takes some time to do so)

My Finder Sync Extension's Info.Plist.
[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My Finder Integration</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.FinderSync</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>FinderSync</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © **** All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Please add the content of your info.plist to your Q.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad added the screenshot of my finder sync extension plist.

Comment: Is this the complete plist? Don't add it as image.

Comment: Have you found ? Enabling/disabling works as expected for me: starts or stops the extension.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH15-SW1), the value for the key `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` should include the module name separated by a `.`:

```
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).FinderSync</string>
```

Comment: I tried that out, but doing so causes my extension to crash. 

Question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117848/adding-product-module-name-to-nsextensionprincipalclass-in-findersync-plist-cras